# How to transfer click event to button below Gridview?

Tags: android, button, gridview, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I have tried everything but I am not getting the idea how to do it?

I have a gridview which is overlapping a button and when I click on the button the click event is not getting transferred to the button because gridview is overlapping it. I can't put button above the gridview because it will ruin the design is there any way to achieve it. This diagram would explain better.
[image]

here is my xml code I don't think sharing java code would make sense.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/browser_sub_drawer_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/browser_sub_drawer_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/browser_sub_header_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="340dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:visibility="invisible">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/browser_sub_header_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="340dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/black_to_transparent_gradient"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/browser_sub_header_text_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/black_to_transparent_gradient">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/browser_sub_header_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:ellipsize="marquee"
                        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                        android:paddingRight="12dp"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                        android:shadowColor="#FF454545"
                        android:shadowDx="0"
                        android:shadowDy="0"
                        android:shadowRadius="5"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Header Text"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="24sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/browser_sub_header_sub_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/browser_sub_header_text"
                        android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
                        android:ellipsize="marquee"
                        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                        android:paddingRight="12dp"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                        android:shadowColor="#FF454545"
                        android:shadowDx="0"
                        android:shadowDy="0"
                        android:shadowRadius="5"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Subtext"
                        android:textColor="#FF999999"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/browser_sub_play_all"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/play_all_caps"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="12sp"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="#BB000000"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/browser_sub_grid_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:horizontalSpacing="3.5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:paddingRight="6dp"
                android:paddingTop="280dp"
                android:verticalSpacing="3.5dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please note gridview covers the whole screen I have given top padding.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share more details like your code

Comment: @VinayagaSundar Please have a look P.S. I am using simple adapter and onClikitemlistener for the gridview and clicklistener for the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was pretty simple though it took me time to figure out here is the code.

```
mGridView.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
            MotionEvent e = MotionEvent.obtain(event);
            //view to which you want to dispatch the motionevent.
            mHeaderLayout.dispatchTouchEvent(e);
            e.recycle();
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/browser_sub_drawer_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/browser_sub_drawer_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/browser_sub_header_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="340dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:visibility="invisible">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/browser_sub_header_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="340dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/black_to_transparent_gradient"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/browser_sub_header_text_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/black_to_transparent_gradient">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/browser_sub_header_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:ellipsize="marquee"
                        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                        android:paddingRight="12dp"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                        android:shadowColor="#FF454545"
                        android:shadowDx="0"
                        android:shadowDy="0"
                        android:shadowRadius="5"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Header Text"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="24sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/browser_sub_header_sub_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/browser_sub_header_text"
                        android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
                        android:ellipsize="marquee"
                        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                        android:paddingRight="12dp"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                        android:shadowColor="#FF454545"
                        android:shadowDx="0"
                        android:shadowDy="0"
                        android:shadowRadius="5"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Subtext"
                        android:textColor="#FF999999"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/browser_sub_play_all"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/play_all_caps"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="12sp"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="#BB000000"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/browser_sub_grid_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:horizontalSpacing="3.5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:paddingRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
                android:verticalSpacing="3.5dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I told you I can't change the design when you would scroll all the items of the gridview will go above overlapping the button and image like parallax when gridview is all the way down and button is visible then that button should be clickable.

Comment: Then try to use coordinate layout in Android

Comment: co-ordinate layout wont work like I want it to work its like image and button are static and when you will scroll up gridviews item would go above overlapping them.

Comment: Maybe BottomSheet will help. it's my final solution for you.
[Ref Here](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031)

Comment: Thanks for trying but It won't may b I would put gif or video in the question to make it more clear.